# Gaussian Processes: advice on proper optimization settings for simple model?

Tags: regression, python, nonparametric, gaussian-process

I am trying my hand at Gaussian Processes with GPflow (basically using [this basic example](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/basics/regression.ipynb) as my guide), and am experiencing difficulties fitting some basic periodic data which I generated.

**My code:**

```
## Data generation

x = np.linspace(0,20, num=150)
noise = np.random.normal(0,0.3,150)
y = np.sin(x) + noise

plt.scatter(x, y)

## Some pre-processing

X_sin = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
Y_sin = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

test_X_sin_1dim = np.linspace(-20,40,500)
test_X_sin_2dim = np.expand_dims(test_X_sin_1dim, axis=1)

## Model

with gpflow.defer_build():

        m = gpflow.models.GPR(X_sin, Y_sin, kern = gpflow.kernels.Periodic(1))

m.as_pandas_table()

m.compile()

opt = gpflow.train.ScipyOptimizer(options=dict(maxiter=1000))
opt.minimize(m)

## Plotting predictions

f = m.predict_y(test_X_sin_2dim)
upper = f[0] + f[1]/2
lower = f[0] - f[1]/2
lower = lower.squeeze()
upper = upper.squeeze()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill_between(test_X_sin_1dim, lower, upper)

ax.scatter(x_sin, y_sin, color='r', marker='x', s=9, label='Data')
ax.plot(test_X_sin_1dim, f[0], color='#FFA500', linewidth=0.5, label='Forecast Mean')

ax.set_xlim([-20, 40])
ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
```

**Resulting prediction:**

(red is original data, orange is predicted mean, blue area is forecast interval)

[image: capturing]

As can be seen, the periodic kernel fails completely in capturing this simple oscillation, which concerns me since that is the period kernel's basic purpose, and this data is rather straightforward (centered around 0, and having little noise).

Changing the `gpflow.train` optimizer, from the default Scipy one to another like `gpflow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`, does not change much, and the docs do not provide much other guidance.

Would any more experienced modelers help me understand the right settings/etc needed in order to fit this basic curve? I will be extremely grateful for any help

**EDIT:**

Maybe a better way to phrase my question is *"why does my optimization end so quickly"*?

[image]

If I *force* my model to focus on the most important parameter (`period` within `gpflow.kernels.Periodic(1)`), inserting the following just before `m.compile`,

```
m.kern.lengthscales.trainable = False
m.kern.variance.trainable = False
m.likelihood.variance.trainable = False
```

, I get better results, meaning I am on the right path.

[image]

Comment: I will expand on this probably but what we want is a good old decent random initialisation. If we define the kernel as: `k = gpflow.kernels.Periodic(input_dim=1, period=5)` we are good to go with the original algorithm/script. The default `L-BFGS-B` does not use the Hessian and that hurts it greatly. Multiple minima are annoying. We might want to consider first HMC-ing this and then using a gradient based method.

Comment: How would you recommend combining the two methods? Isn't that just using MCMC the whole way?

Comment: I was planning to write more but then I just noticed that the `HMC` has a [bug](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/894) at the moment. My basic idea would be to MCMC at first to make sure do hit any horrible plateaus and then gradient our way to the minimum. Which being us to the point of the paper Mishkin &  Matas ["All you need is a good init"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422).

Comment: That is very interesting, and I am about to read that paper. Is there a technical name for using MCMC to initialize, and then switching over to gradients?

Comment: Just "hybrid approach" or "two-stage" is very straightforward. For example, in linear mixed effects models, it was not uncommon to do first a few (slow) EM steps that were guarantee not to diverge and then pass the next stage to a Newton optimiser. The package `nlme` still does that. By far the most influencial recent paper on the matter is Bergstra & Bengio's [Random Search for Hyper-Parameter Optimization](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf). (I probably should write all this into an answer...)